# creating and printing cookies in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to create cookies in PHP and not use sessions. This is how I am creating them:

```
echo 'Successfully registered :)';
$name = $_POST['user_name'];
setcookie("name", $name);
```

This is at the bottom of the page once everything is done. I see the echoed line on the page and I also know that $_POST['user_name']; contains a value. So the cookie should be set. At the top of the same page right below the `<body>` tag I have `echo $_COOKIE['name'];`. When I reload the page I do not see anything and it is a blank page. I can paste the whole page but it is ~150 lines.

Comment: Enable proper PHP error reporting, and go read the manual for [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), _carefully_.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the PHP manual, `setcookie()` must be called before any output is made.

Btw. this has potential to create a nice XSS, you should really really filter the POST variable before reflecting it as cookie content.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers, which means that it needs to be set before any page markup or anything else. [PHP Cookie Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Also, you'll want to sanitize any user input to prevent any malicious doings. As of PHP 5.2 [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) has been introduced which can be used in this case.